# How to routine traffic to different service version but having the same proto package name?

Tags: grpc

We use SemVer to tag our service but keep the same "package v1" in all the proto files.
For example, our git tags can be "v.1.1.1" then "v1.2.0" but all the .proto files still have the same "package v1". The reason is we don't want to change that across all files.
Now we want to deploy "v1.1.1" together with "v1.2.0" for kind of blue/green deployment and using a special client code to test the new one.
If this is an REST API, clients code can simply having the version within their path, then we can have some rewrite rules on the gateway, I guess I can do the same but the issue seem generate clients code (at least for Golang) won't let me to override the path.   Is there anyway to do it "native" from gRPC?
Maybe we do it wrong from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy the differently versioned servers to different hosts|ports, i.e.

- v1.1.1 --> :10111
- v1.2.0 --> :10120

If the protos aren't changed, then the proto versions should not change but it''s entirely reasonable that your implementations (client or server) would version independently of the protos.

Because the proto is the same (version), the messages sent|received (on-the-wire) don't change and so you can only disambiguate these services outside of gRPC, i.e. e.g. putting them on different endpoints.

Another way you may be able to do this would be to inject client|server version metadata into the messages. You could then read these (interceptors) at either end to determine which implementation version originated them.